# FORTRAN: passing a dummy argument to a subroutine

Tags: fortran

I am pretty new to Fortran and have a problem to solve.

I have a subroutine declared somewhere and sometimes in my program I do not wish to compute a particular part of that subroutine. I could duplicate the subroutine but is not neat programming.

The way I wanted to solve this is by passing a dummy argument:

declaration of subroutine:

```
subroutinename(...,r,dr,d2r)
```

call with dummy argument:

```
call subroutinename(...,r,dr,dummy)
   IF (d2r.NE.dummy)...
```

I tried to implement but I have a problem. d2r is a matrix so how do I pass a value that can be used as a logical for the IF statement part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional arguments in Fortran 90 and later.

```
subroutine subroutinename(...,r,dr,d2r)
  real, optional :: d2r(:,:)

  if (present(d2r)) then
    !do the computation
  end if
```

you call it with the `d2r` argument or not

```
call subroutinename(...,r,dr,d2r)

call subroutinename(...,r,dr)
```

Optional arguments require explicit interface. That is best ensured by placing the subroutine in a module.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `optional` arguments:

```
subroutine subroutinename(r,dr,d2r)
  ! 
  real, intent(in)            :: r(:)
  real, intent(out)           :: dr(:)
  real, intent(out), optional :: d2r(:)

  ! ...
  if ( present(d2r) ) then
    ! Only execute this if d2r is present
  endif
  ! ...
end subroutine
```